# iOS Swift: order of code execution / asynchronous execution

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous

If I run the below code in swift, are steps 1., 2., 3., and 4. always executed in this order (as they should), or is there a risk of asynchronous execution if the loop, the sorting, etc., take longer than expected?

```
  // 1.
  for i in self.filtered{
      for j in i.calls {
          var jj = j
          jj.uid = i.uid
          self.CallList.append(jj)
      }
  }
  // 2.
  self.CallList.sort { $0.priceHist > $1.priceHist }
  // 3.      
  self.filtered = self.CallList
  // 4.
  self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: You have no asynchronous execution in the code shown. It will all execute in order. By the way, by convention your array property should be `callList` not `CallList`.

Comment: There's only a risk of asynchronous execution if you use asynchronous execution. Your question isn't very clear. Why are you concerned with asynchronous execution if the code you posted doesn't use any?

Comment: I think OP assumes that the block passed to `sort` is `@escaping`.

Comment: @Samah whether it is `@escaping` or not does not determine whether a closure executed asynchronously.

Comment: @Paulw11 While `@escaping` does not necessarily indicate asynchronicity, please show me an example of a non-escaping closure that's executed asynchronously.

Comment: All ducks are birds, but not all birds are ducks.  It is true that asynchronously executed closures are escaping, but not all escaping enclosures are executed asynchronously.

Comment: That was exactly my point.

Comment: No, that's my point.  You suggested that the OP may have believed that closure passed to `sort` was escaping which implies that it is executed asynchronously.  This is an incorrect logical conclusion, just as if the closure passed to `sort` was a bird and determining that, therefore, it is a duck.

Comment: If `if a then b` is true, then `if not b then not a` is also true. (The contrapositive, in logic.) `if its async, the closure must be escaping` implies `if the closure isn't an escaping closure, it can't be async.`

Comment: @Paulw11, in that sense, Samah is technically correct, even though what he said is confusing, and perhaps even misleading. It **is** correct to say "if the closure isn't escaping, it can't be async."

Comment: @DuncanC We don't really need to continue this, but he said "I think OP assumes that the block passed to sort is `@escaping`." If the block is `@escaping` then it may be executed asynchronously or synchronously. If the block is `@nonescaping` then the block can only be executed synchronously. In other words "if @escaping then asynchronous" is *not true*. "If @nonescaping then synchronous" *is true* so you can say "if not synchronous then not @nonescaping". So, if Samah had said "I think op assumes block passed to `sort` is asynchronous" then they would have been correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can be certain that your code will be run in order 1, 2, 3, 4.

Every step in the code you posted is performed synchronously. It completes the entire for loop, then the sort, then assigns to the filtered property, then tells the table view to reload.

Functions that do asynchronous tasks are documented as such. Usually such functions take a completion handler so that you can invoke code once they finish their task.

Comment: Thank you Duncan. I didn't realise that it's only special functions with asynchronous property that get executed asynchronously. Your answer makes that clear.